# SimHash implementation in Java?

Tags: java, hash, simhash

Has anyone come across a [simhash](http://matpalm.com/resemblance/simhash/) function implemented in Java?

I've already searched for it, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: +1. Hadn't heard of this before. Interesting thread.

Comment: Yes, they can be quite useful - unlike a normal hash, which attempts to be generate a sparsely populated hash space given a set of similar strings (i.e. generating dissimilar hashes) a simhash attempts to generate similar, local, hash values for similar strings.

Comment: That link says "hash each feature using a normal 32-bit hash algorithm"; i suspect that in Java, using [String's hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) would not be a good move for that, since for two-character strings, it boils down to `s[0]*31 + s[1]`, which is only a 20-bit number, and will have lots of zeroes in the upper of those 20 bits if the two characters are ASCII. A better option might be something like `(((long)s[0]) + 1) * (((long)((~s[0]) & 0xffff)) + 1) -1`.

Comment: @TomAnderson, [Guava's `HashFunction`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/HashFunction.html#hashString%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) provides better fast non-crypto-strong hashing.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Guava's `HashFunction` is an interface, and as such, doesn't provide anything. However, it's very likely that some implementations of it do provide better hashes - i see there are some good ones in [`Hashing`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html). That said, in this particular case, we are only ever hashing two-character strings, so we don't need a good general-purpose hash algorithm; something simple might be good enough. Still, Murmur3-32 should definitely be good enough - as long as it's a revision from 2011-1-4 or later.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: The trouble with that is that it isn't a very good hash. If you take a pair of letters and change one of them, no more than half the bits will change, and in all probability, only a few will (eg 'ba' to 'ca' is only a single bit). A good hash would avalanche the change across the whole hash. Murmur3 does this; one could use that, or, because we're only starting with 32 bits, just use its [finalization step](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/source/browse/trunk/MurmurHash3.cpp?spec=svn136&r=136#66).

Comment: @MikeSamuel: In this context, that's not how the hash is being used. Have a read of the simhash document that Joel linked to in the question.

Answer (score 4):

btw. It looks like Google has [patented](https://image-ppubs.uspto.gov/dirsearch-public/print/downloadPdf/7158961) the algorithm. If you are in US, successfully compete with Google, and do not have own parent portfolio, then do not tell them you are using it.

An implementation in C

[http://dsrg.mff.cuni.cz/~holub/sw/shash/](http://dsrg.mff.cuni.cz/%7Eholub/sw/shash/)

---

[Removed no longer relevant BibSonomy text]

Comment: based on the research from when i wrote that post there are loads of variants on sketching/simhash that aren't specifically the charikar implementation. if you look at the references in the actual paper you can hunt them down.

Comment: "sorry, we couldn't find this patent number." @jitter, could you please update the link?

Comment: @naXastandswithUkraine done

Comment: @jitter - It appears that the patent has now expired and anyone should be okay to use: https://patents.google.com/patent/US7158961.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the full java source code. It's very simple.
A demo also is provided.
http://aneurone.blogspot.com/2012/09/simhash.html

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to (like I did).

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time, the [hash4j library](https://github.com/dynatrace-oss/hash4j) includes a SimHash Java implementation. There is also a FastSimHash implementation, which is up to 10x faster using a bit hack as described in [this blog post](https://engineering.dynatrace.com/blog/speeding-up-simhash-by-10x-using-a-bit-hack/).

Answer (score -2):

According to [this page](http://www.gbv.de/wikis/cls/Bibliographic_Hash_Key), you should ask the developers of [BibSonomy](http://www.bibsonomy.org/).

Comment: It it just that there is a mention of a class on that page called SimHash.java, or does that that class actually implements the simhash algorithm as defined in the link in the question?